# service bus 1.0 not showing up in windows platform installer 4.5

Tags: azure, servicebus

I am trying to install Service Bus 1.0 on my developer machine. When i am searching for "Service Bus 1.0" in the web platform installer 4.5, it is not able to find it.

I downloaded .exe file manually from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=252361. When the setup runs, it gives me an error message in Web Platform Installer that `"Microsoft web platform installer couldn't find the product you tried to install. Either the link you clicked is incorrect or you may be overriding you feed with different feed."`

I checked my feed and it is set to `"default"`.

My operating system is windows 7 SP1 Enterprise Edition.
VS 2010 and V2012 installed. I also have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Any idea what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that my OS is 32 bit and it requires 64 bit OS.